# show/hide visibility by classname not ById

Tags: javascript, hide, show, getelementsbyclassname

I am using this javascript and code to hide/show certain divs but on each click, there are multiple divs on the page that I want to hide/show so I would rather do it by class name. I don't really know javascript so the simpler, the better.

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function show_visibility(){
for(var i = 0,e = arguments.length;i < e;i++){
var myDiv = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style;
myDiv.display = "block";
}
}

function hide_visibility(){
for(var i = 0,e = arguments.length;i < e;i++){
var myDiv = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style;
myDiv.display = "none";
}
}
//--></script>
```

Here is the html:

```
<ul id="menubar_index" style="display:block;" class="index">
    <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="show_visibility('menubar_how');hide_visibility('menubar_index') ">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="menubar_how" style="display:none;" class="howitworks">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="show_visibility('menubar_index');hide_visibility('menubar_how') ">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="active">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead of `document.getElementById()`

Comment: I tried using document.getElementsByClassName() instead of document.getElementById() before I posted this question but it didn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You may want:

- [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) / [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) - they will allow you to select elements using CSS-like rules;
- [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) - this one will simply search by class names.